# how to double count column which already counted

Tags: sql

Please help me to solve the problem

My real table is:

```
id     group      numberOfLevel(counted column)
 1     10              4
 2     10              2
 3     11              2 
 4     11              1 
 5     11              3
 6     11              2
 7     21              1
 8     21              2 
 9     30              1 
 10    40              2
```

But i want to show:

```
group    1st_level      2nd_level    3rd_level     over4th_level
 10         0              1            0                1 
 11         1              2            1                0
 21         1              1            0                0 
 30         1              0            0                0 
 40         0              1            0                0
```

Which way do i need to use to show the table? 
Please share experience ?

Comment: This type of query is known as a pivot, and its implementation will depend on the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic pivot query, an ANSII SQL case expession can be used in such a query,

and it should work on most databases:

```
select group_nr,
       sum( case when numberOfLevel = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) As level_1st,
       sum( case when numberOfLevel = 2 then 1 else 0  end ) As level_2nd,
       sum( case when numberOfLevel = 3 then 1 else 0  end ) As level_3rd,
       sum( case when numberOfLevel >= 4 then 1 else 0  end ) As over4th_level
from table1
group by group_nr
;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bd04/4

Don't use `group` as a column name, because `group` is a keyword in SQL.